# Microsoft graph api returning incomplete json

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Trying to make a call to the ms graph api to capture the ids of emails of a particular user, and it works fine for the first 1000 items, but when i try to send the next requests using the *skip* param, it sends back incomplete json.

for ref, here's my request `GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/messages?%24select=id&%24top=1000&%24skip=1081"` (it's the autogenerated @odata.nextLink)

Comment: Outside of your code, can you try to repro the issue with Graph Explorer?

Comment: Are you modifying the skip parameter?

Comment: Can you also please expand on what you mean by "incomplete"?

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma i'm not adding an modifications to the skip parameter, just using the one autogenerated in the odata.nextLink

Comment: @MarcLaFleur what I mean by "incomplete", is that the response body simply just gets cut off at an arbitrary point. Like the endpoint is not returning all the bytes it should be, resulting in "incomplete" json.